# Full version of Texstudio

Tags: beamer, texstudio

Can someone suggest how to install the full version of Texstudio in Mac? Some of my beamer files can not be compiled due to some missing packages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uninstall whatever you have and install MacTeX from here https://www.tug.org/mactex/ and TeXstudio from here https://www.texstudio.org/#download

Comment: Remember TeXStudio does not have anything to do with which packages are installed on your system. It is just a front end that can edit text files and call other programmes. It is your LaTeX distribution who is responsible for the packages you have. As Henri already mentioned, install a new MacTeX (it is the easiest latex to install on all platforms, if you have the space there is no need to uninstall the old one). If that does not work, show us the errors you get.